# why im getting an error when i lunch mvn verify?

Tags: maven

-The web app is at this link https://github.com/exo-archives/acceptance

-the stack trace :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project acceptance-webapp: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\acceptance\acceptance\acceptance-webapp\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Check your tests as JF Meier already stated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your unit tests. Fix them first.